# Not enough "usable memory". Possible to trick Windows into thinking it has more?

Tags: windows-10, memory, gaming

I am trying to install Forza on my Alienware 13 R3, which came with 8gb of RAM. The minimum requirement to download Forza is 12gb of RAM (it's not gonna let me download it if I don't have that much RAM). I bought a 4gb RAM stick just so I can play Forza and put it in my laptop, but now it's saying I've got 11.9gb of RAM.

Is there any way to trick Windows into thinking it has 12gb of RAM? I don't wanna buy another RAM stick since I've already filled up two of the available slots (meaning I'll have to sell the 4gb RAM stick if I buy another 8gb RAM stick)

[image: Memory]

Comment: How much RAM is showing in BIOS?

Comment: @wysiwyg 12288MB (http://imgur.com/a/W6ruI)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/1170803/how-to-trick-windows-10-into-thinking-it-has-more-ram-then-it-does

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Trick Windows 10 Into Thinking it Has More RAM Then it Does?](http://superuser.com/questions/1170803/how-to-trick-windows-10-into-thinking-it-has-more-ram-then-it-does)

Comment: @DavidPostill - Came across that one too. Thats for Win32, won't work with UWP (UWP doesn't allow DLL injections)

Comment: I'm a little confused. The *minimum* requirement is clearly 8 GB. It also has a green tick so ypu shouldn't have any problems at all...?

Comment: While I would consider this odd in a gaming laptop, it is not abnormal for laptops to offer some of their memory to the GPU. This setting (and others regarding memory reservations) are found in the computer BIOS.

Comment: @DanielB The install button was grayed out

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Forums on Tomshardware](http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-3051291/bypass-hardware-requirements-forza-motorsport-apex.html) discuss a potential solution for Forza Motorsport 6 Apex, worth a try:

> hold page up on your keyboard and click exit at the sametime and then it will bypass it.

Answer (score -1):

That is due to the fact that some of the RAM is allocated for the performance of your hardware.  So, it would not be possible to manipulate that value, unless, you are able to write a kind of strict script which runs against whichever checks Forza has in place.

Comment: I'm not an IT person so I don't know how to write scripts. But what you're saying makes sense, just wish that there was a way to trick it. If you'll be able to write a script that does this for me, I'll pay you 0.025 BTC for it